# Is there a window function or combination of window functions that I can use to get this desired result via TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions

Take the below table for instance:

```
ORDER_KEY  |   STATUS_DATE   | TASK_CREATED_DATE |  TASK_KEY  | TASK_ROW_ID | TASK_REVISION_ID 
-----------|-----------------|-------------------|------------|-------------|------------------ 
1274796898 | 10/4/2019 18:19 | 10/4/2019 18:12   | 5277852673 |           1 |                  
1274796898 | 10/4/2019 18:19 | 10/4/2019 18:12   | 5277852674 |           2 |                  
1274796898 | 10/4/2019 18:19 | 4/7/2020 14:22    | 5277853673 |           3 |                1 
1274796898 | 10/4/2019 18:19 | 4/7/2020 14:22    | 5277853674 |           4 |                1 
1274796898 | 10/4/2019 18:19 | 4/7/2020 14:22    | 5277853675 |           5 |                1 
1274737653 | 10/4/2019 15:32 | 10/4/2019 15:31   | 5277852586 |           1 |                  
1274737653 | 10/4/2019 15:32 | 10/4/2019 15:31   | 5277852587 |           2 |                  
1274737653 | 10/4/2019 15:32 | 10/4/2019 15:31   | 5277852588 |           3 |                  
1274737653 | 10/4/2019 15:32 | 10/4/2019 15:32   | 5277852589 |           4 |                  
1274737647 | 10/4/2019 11:49 | 10/4/2019 11:42   | 5277855586 |           1 |                  
1274737647 | 10/4/2019 11:49 | 10/4/2019 11:42   | 5277855587 |           2 |                  
1274737647 | 10/4/2019 11:49 | 10/4/2019 11:42   | 5277855588 |           3 |                  
1274737647 | 10/4/2019 11:49 | 10/4/2019 11:42   | 5277855589 |           4 |                  
1274737647 | 10/4/2019 11:49 | 10/4/2019 11:42   | 5277855590 |           5 |                  
1274737647 | 10/4/2019 11:49 | 10/4/2019 11:49   | 5277855587 |           6 |                  
1274737647 | 10/4/2019 11:49 | 10/4/2019 11:49   | 5277856270 |           7 |                  
1274737647 | 10/4/2019 11:49 | 4/7/2020 14:10    | 5281403575 |           8 |                1 
1274737647 | 10/4/2019 11:49 | 4/7/2020 14:10    | 5281403576 |           9 |                1 
1274737647 | 10/4/2019 11:49 | 4/7/2020 14:12    | 5281403595 |          10 |                1 
1274737647 | 10/4/2019 11:49 | 4/14/2020 09:32   | 5281403599 |          11 |                2 
1274737647 | 10/4/2019 11:49 | 4/26/2020 13:10   | 5281403600 |          12 |                3
```

which can be reproduced with the following query:

```sql
with data as (
    select *
    from (
      values
      (1274796898, '10/4/2019 18:19', '10/4/2019 18:12', 5277852673,   1), 
      (1274796898, '10/4/2019 18:19', '10/4/2019 18:12', 5277852674,   2), 
      (1274796898, '10/4/2019 18:19', '4/7/2020 14:22', 5277853673,   3), 
      (1274796898, '10/4/2019 18:19', '4/7/2020 14:22', 5277853674,   4), 
      (1274796898, '10/4/2019 18:19', '4/7/2020 14:22', 5277853675,   5), 
      (1274737653, '10/4/2019 15:32', '10/4/2019 15:31', 5277852586,   1), 
      (1274737653, '10/4/2019 15:32', '10/4/2019 15:31', 5277852587,   2), 
      (1274737653, '10/4/2019 15:32', '10/4/2019 15:31', 5277852588,   3), 
      (1274737653, '10/4/2019 15:32', '10/4/2019 15:32', 5277852589,   4), 
      (1274737647, '10/4/2019 11:49', '10/4/2019 11:42', 5277855586,   1), 
      (1274737647, '10/4/2019 11:49', '10/4/2019 11:42', 5277855587,   2), 
      (1274737647, '10/4/2019 11:49', '10/4/2019 11:42', 5277855588,   3), 
      (1274737647, '10/4/2019 11:49', '10/4/2019 11:42', 5277855589,   4), 
      (1274737647, '10/4/2019 11:49', '10/4/2019 11:42', 5277855590,   5), 
      (1274737647, '10/4/2019 11:49', '10/4/2019 11:49', 5277855587,   6), 
      (1274737647, '10/4/2019 11:49', '10/4/2019 11:49', 5277856270,   7), 
      (1274737647, '10/4/2019 11:49', '4/7/2020 14:10', 5281403575,   8), 
      (1274737647, '10/4/2019 11:49', '4/7/2020 14:10', 5281403576,   9), 
      (1274737647, '10/4/2019 11:49', '4/7/2020 14:12', 5281403595,  10), 
      (1274737647, '10/4/2019 11:49', '4/14/2020 09:32', 5281403599,  11), 
      (1274737647, '10/4/2019 11:49', '4/26/2020 13:10', 5281403600,  12)
    ) v (ORDER_KEY, STATUS_DATE, TASK_CREATED_DATE, TASK_KEY, TASK_ROW_ID)
)
select * from data;
```

The behaviour I'm ultimately looking to achieve is the **`TASK_REVISION_ID` column output**.
In the data above, it has been manually inputted for illustration purposes.

```sql
TASK_ROW_ID = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ORDER_KEY ORDER BY TASK_CREATED_DATE, TASK_KEY)
```

At an `ORDER_KEY` level, I want to increment the `TASK_REVISION_ID` in the following fashion:

1. Set `TASK_REVISION_ID` to 1 when `TASK_CREATED_DATE` > `STATUS_DATE`
2. Increment `TASK_REVISION_ID` when the difference in minutes between Current Row `TASK_CREATED_DATE` and Previous Row `TASK_CREATED_DATE` >= 5

Comment: That samle data isn't consumable for us. Please take the time to provide DDL and DML statements, or tabular formatted `text`. Along with that, what are your expected results? What were your attempts and why didnt they work?

Comment: Does my table pic assist at all ?

Comment: `Does my table pic assist at all?` - [not really](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). I'm not retyping that.

Comment: how can i embed my table while maintaining legibility in this post ?

Comment: By posting the data as tabular formatted `text` or DDL and DML statements, @DeeRinos , as I mentioned in my first comment.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/220127/147640

Comment: Thank you GSerg, i'll post again based on that links' guidelines.

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: What's wrong with `ROW_NUMBER` here, seems like you're just after it's value minus 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to amend the [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62010462/11683) that shows the correct idea ever so slightly:

```sql
select
  d.ORDER_KEY, d.STATUS_DATE, d.TASK_CREATED_DATE, d.TASK_KEY, d.TASK_ROW_ID, 
  task_revision_id = (
    case when grp = 1
    then sum(case when datediff(mi, prev_tcd, TASK_CREATED_DATE) > 5 or grp_first = 1 then 1 else 0 end) over
                      (partition by d.order_key, d.grp order by task_row_id)
    end
  )
from
  (select d.*,
          lag(TASK_CREATED_DATE) over (partition by order_key order by task_row_id) as prev_tcd,
          case when task_created_date > status_date then 1 else 0 end as grp,
          case when lag(case when task_created_date > status_date then 1 else 0 end, 1, 0) over (partition by order_key order by task_row_id) = 0 then 1 else 0 end as grp_first
   from
      data d
  ) d 
order by
  order_key,
  task_row_id
```

Comment: Thank you GSerg very much. Your version of the original solution provided by Gordon did the trick. Thank you to you both for helping me resolve my issue. Keep up the GREAT WORK!!!

Answer (score 3):

This answers the original version of the question.

What you are describing is captured by this query:

```
select (case when grp = 1
             then sum(case when prev_tcd > dateadd(minute, -5, TASK_CREATED_DATE) then 0 else 1 end) over
                      (partition by d.order_key, v.grp order by task_created_date)
        end),
       d.*
from (select d.*,
             lag(TASK_CREATED_DATE) over (partition by order_key order by TASK_CREATED_DATE) as prev_tcd
      from data d
     ) d cross apply
     (values ((case when task_created_date > status_date then 1 else 0 end))) v(grp)
order by 1, 2, 3;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9de8d1f387df9667026b4bfc326f7468) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however I'm trying to output the same "TASK_REVISION_ID" output from ASCII table illustration included. The above SQL solution yields different results.

Comment: I spoke too soon. Thank you very much Gordon :) This yielded exactly what I was looking for after casting all the date fields as DATE

Comment: Hi Gordon, any ideas about that additional scenario as why it's yielding a 0 instead of a 1 for task_revision_id ?

Comment: @DeeRinos . . . Can you ask a new question, with appropriate sample data and explanation?

Comment: I had edited your answer post, with hopes of retaining the same context, but it says it's only visible to me still until trusted community members approve it. Sample data and additional explanation was supplied therein.

Comment: @DeeRinos It looks like you edited this answer to contain a question. That is not how this website works. If this answer is actually wrong, unaccept it and comment why it's wrong.

Comment: Unaccepted for time being, please see additional comments above.

Comment: @DeeRinos That's because in your requirements you have `TASK_CREATED_DATE > STATUS_DATE`, but in [that dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/26235421) it's `TASK_CREATED_DATE = STATUS_DATE`, so the revision is (correctly) never set to 1. You probably meant `TASK_CREATED_DATE >= STATUS_DATE` to begin with, which you can change in the `case when task_created_date > status_date then 1 else 0 end` in this answer - but then it also changes the "correct" outcome for your original dataset from the question.

Comment: It needs to be TASK_CREATED_DATE > STATUS_DATE, in the new example i included TASK_CREATED_DATE (1/10/2017 12:42) is greater than STATUS_DATE (1/10/2017 12:41) but it gives 0 for those instead of 1 ultimately ?

Comment: @DeeRinos You are correct. This code assumes that the first revision (`TASK_REVISION_ID = 1`) must be more than 5 minutes apart from the previous time, like all subsequent revisions. This was never a requirement.